# How to use the CTCLoss in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I've been building a LipNet model with cross entropy loss but the model does a pretty bad job in learning to predict the correct words. So I switched to CTCLoss (which was the same loss used in the official lipnet paper) however the model is not learning anything.
The model is a Conv-LSTM network, takes an input video of tensor (batch_size, 1, 75, 46, 140) and outputs a tensor of shape ( batch_size , 10)  which is fed to the lstm.

Here is the code.

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_size, hidden_size):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size , embed_size)
    self.model = nn.LSTM(self.embed_size, self.hidden_size,num_layers = 2 , batch_first=True , bidirectional = True )
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    self.ln = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*2, self.vocab_size)
    self.conv = Conv()
    self.m = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
  def forward(self , features, sentence):
    
    features = self.conv(features)

    print(features.shape)
    x = torch.Tensor().to(device)
    sentences = torch.Tensor().to(device)
    states = None
    for i in range(36):
              out , states = self.model(features.unsqueeze(1), states)
#               print(out.shape)                         size: (batch_size , 1 , 10)
                 
              out = self.ln(out)
#               print(out.shape)                         size :  (batch , 1 , 40)
              
#               print(out)
              x = torch.cat((x , out) , dim = 1)


              pred = out.squeeze(1).argmax(1)                 

              features = self.embeddings(pred).to(device)
              # features_shape = (batch , 1 , 10)
# x_shape: (batch_size , 36 , 40)

    return x
   
  def sample(self , x , max_length):
         words = []
         with torch.no_grad():
           features = self.conv(x)
           print("df" , features.shape)
           states = None

#              print(features.shape)
            
         return words
```

Here is how I trained the model.

```
criterion = nn.CTCLoss()
for j in range(300):
  print(j , "EPOCHS")
  for m , (x , y) in enumerate(tqdm(train_data)):
    x = x.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
    x = x.to(device)
    Y = np.array(y)
    y = np.array(y)
    y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    y = y.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
    y = y.to(device)
    print(x.shape)

    sen = model(x , y)
    sentence = sen[: , 1: , : ] #the model returns tensor shape (36 , 40)
    word = [ ]
    words= [ ]
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
      for n in range(35):
         max = torch.argmax(sentence[i][n])
         word.append(max.cpu().detach().numpy())
      words.append(word)
      word = []
   
    words = np.stack(words , axis=0)
  
    
   
#   print(words.shape)
    word = itos(words[0])
  
    words = torch.from_numpy(words)
    words = words.to(device)

#   print(y.shape , sentence.shape)           y_shape: (batch , 35 , 40)  , sentence : (batch , 35 , 40)

    sentence = torch.permute(sentence , (1 , 0 , 2)
#   print(sentence.shape)                                         (35 , batch , 40) 
    lengths = torch.full(size=(x.shape[0],), fill_value=1, dtype= torch.int)
    loss = criterion(sentence , y, lengths  , lengths)
  
    optimizer.zero_grad() 
    loss.backward(loss)
    optimizer.step()
  print("Predicted word: " , word)
  print("Actual word:    " , itos(Y[0]))
```

But the output is something like this:

```
0 EPOCHS
100%|██████████| 57/57 [00:11<00:00,  4.80it/s]
Predicted word:  3vvv3v3vv3v3vv3v3vv3v3vv3v3vv3v3vv3
Actual word:     lay blue with r three soon ''''''''
```

And it stays like this for all the epochs
can you please explain what is it that I'm doing wrong, am I giving wrong inputs to the criterion(CTCLoss) or is it something else.